# Ionic2/Angular2 - Hide the back button on the modal view that was inherited from the navigation view

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a modal view, once an element inside that modal is clicked, it goes to a navigation view (normally a back button appears). The issue is that, when you pop back from the navigation to the modal, a new back button appears (that's the one I want to hide) besides to the close button I have already on the modal.

Any ideas on how to hide the back button from the modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the **hideBackButton** directive

```
<ion-navbar hideBackButton *navbar primary>
    <ion-title>My Page</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button (click)="dismiss()">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't seen [this document on ionic modals](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#modals) have a look. You should be able to just delete the close/back button that comes with it if you already have a back button. Make sure you don't have this in your modal template:

```
<button (click)="close()">Close</button>
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the close button, I only want to remove the back button